# Map an array using JsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

Is it possible to use **JSONPath** to map a JSON array into another with fewer fields and abbreviated keys?

I'm dealing with a RESTful API which is extremely verbose. It has way too many fields and then each object has very long attribute names. I want to project/map the output into a smaller payload, by only selecting a few fields out of each occurrence in the array and by renaming the fields to three letter keys.

Meaning, from an input like this:

```
[
    {
        "fooField": "foo1",
        "barField": "bar1",
        "quxField": "qux1"
    },
    {
        "fooField": "foo2",
        "barField": "bar2",
        "quxField": "qux2"
    },
    {
        "fooField": "foo3",
        "barField": "bar3",
        "quxField": "qux3"
    }
]
```

I'd like to be able to produce this:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "foo1",
        "bar": "bar1"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo2",
        "bar": "bar2"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo3",
        "bar": "bar3"
    }
]
```

Notice I've renamed the `fooField` and `barField` fields and dropped the `quxField` completely.

Maybe there's no simple way to do this with JSONPath, but I understand there's a script `()` operator that could help, except I've so far been unable to use it and can't seem to find an example.